# How to specify required parameters in AutoRoute? Error RouteArgs can not be null because the corresponding page has a required parameter

Tags: flutter, auto-route

I'm currently evaluation switching from `go_router` to `auto_route` but I'm struggling with

Is it possible to define pages with required parameters with `auto_route`? Something like this:

```
@RoutePage()
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() loadData;

  const ProfilePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.loadData
  }) : super(key: key);
}
```

When I configure this route like this:

```
AutoRoute(
  path: '/profile',
  page: ProfileRoute.page,
),
```

I can't specify the `loadDate` parameter.

On web, when I navigate to the `/profile` path and reload the page, I get the error `ProfileRouteArgs can not be null because the corresponding page has a required parameter`. The same error occurs when making the route as an initial route.

How would I deal with this? Is there any option besides making the parameters of my page optional and setting a default value?

Answer (score 0):

In your class `ProfilePage` function `loadData` is `required`. This is main reason why you got an error:

```
ProfileRouteArgs can not be null because the corresponding page has a required parameter.
```

It is not really about auto_rote. If the parameter of your page is a function and you want to set default value to this param, you could do this:

```
@RoutePage()
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfilePage({
    this.loadData = _getDefaultFunc,
    super.key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Function() loadData;

  static Function() _getDefaultFunc() {
     return (){ ... do something...};
  }
}
```

And of course it could be easily done for other parameter types. More info: [@autoroutePassingArguments](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#passing-arguments)

If you want to use required parameters, then:

```
AutoRouter.of(context).push(
      ProfilePage(
          loadData: (){
             ...do smthng...
          },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know that I could remove the required argument and make it optional with a default value. However, I would much rather keep my required parameters without a default value. It seems like this is not possible with `auto_route` which is unfortunate.

Comment: if you need required parameters then just use it :)